# Listview adapter bugging when refreshing list (loading new details)

Tags: android, listview

I have an awards section where I load data from my server.

I'm pulling 8 by 8 awards from server and loading them in my `ListView`. Awards can be sold and in my adapter I have a checker where if `quantity < 1` there will be a bar over Image that will notify user that award is sold.

There is lazy load where user can swipe to load more details by increasing index, so server can determine which 8 awards should he return. 1 for first 8, 2 for second 8 etc.

Problem is when I scroll to first sold award, ListView gets weird and all awards get that sold bar over their images. This is the code from activity:

```
public class AwardListFragment extends Fragment { int offset = 0;
    int size = 8;
    private int ID;
    private boolean _isAwardsLoaded = false;

    private SwipyRefreshLayout swipyRefreshLayout;
    private ProgressDialog progressBar;
    private ArrayList<Awards> listAwards;
    ListView awardlist;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rewards_section, parent, false);
        awardlist = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.awardlist);
        awardlist.setItemsCanFocus(true);
        listAwards = new ArrayList<>();
        swipyRefreshLayout = (SwipyRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_section_swipe);

      awardlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AwardDetailsScreen.class);
                ID = listAwards.get(position).getId();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("ID", ID);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    }

    public void showlist() {
        progressBar = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressBar.setMessage("Pls Wait...");
        progressBar.show();
        final int firstitemposition = 0;
        final int currentposition = awardlist.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        NetworkSDK.getInstance().getAwards(size, offset, new Callback<List<Awards>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Awards>> call, Response<List<Awards>> response) {
                if (response.code() == 401) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MainPreLogin.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    SharedData.getInstance().removeString("token");

                } else {
                    if (response.isSuccess()) {
                        if (response.body().size() == 0) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "All awards loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressBar.setCancelable(false);
                            progressBar.dismiss();

                        } else
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.body().size(); i++)
                                listAwards.add(response.body().get(i));
                        AwardsAdapter awardsAdapter = new AwardsAdapter(listAwards);
                        awardlist.setAdapter(awardsAdapter);

                        awardsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        awardlist.setSelectionFromTop(currentposition, firstitemposition);

                    }
                    progressBar.setCancelable(false);
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Awards>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.errorNoconnection, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                progressBar.dismiss();

            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser && !_isAwardsLoaded) {
            swipyRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipyRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh(SwipyRefreshLayoutDirection direction) {
                    if (direction == SwipyRefreshLayoutDirection.BOTTOM) {
                        offset++;
                        swipyRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                        showlist();

                    }
                }
     showlist();

            });
                    }
                }
    }
```

This is my adapter.

```
public class AwardsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<Awards> awards;

    public AwardsAdapter(ArrayList<Awards> awards) {
        this.awards = awards;
    }

    public void clearData() {
        // clear the data
        awards.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return awards.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return awards.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = null;
        Integer identity;
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.award_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            view = convertView;
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        }

        Awards awards = (Awards) getItem(position);

        if (awards != null) {
            identity = awards.getId();
            viewHolder.name.setText(awards.getName().toUpperCase());
            viewHolder.price.setText("Money amount: " + awards.getPriceAmount().toString() );
            viewHolder.points.setText("Points amount :" + awards.getCreditAmount().toString());
            if (awards.getImagePath().isEmpty())
                Picasso.with(view.getContext()).load(R.drawable.placeholder).fit().centerCrop().into(viewHolder.picture);
            else
                Picasso.with(view.getContext()).load(awards.getImagePath()).fit().centerCrop().into(viewHolder.picture);
            if (awards.getQuantity()<1)
                Picasso.with(view.getContext()).load(R.drawable.sold).into(viewHolder.checker);
            else
            if (awards.getIsVip())
                Picasso.with(view.getContext()).load(R.drawable.vip).into(viewHolder.checker);
        }

        return view;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView price;
        TextView points;
        ImageView picture;
        ImageView checker;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {

            this.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.award_name);
            this.price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.award_price);
            this.picture = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.award_picture);
            this.points = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.award_points);
            this.checker=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.checker);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a list item reuse issue.

Comment: Yea I think that's it because when i find awards that are sold it go crazy xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your adapter's `getView()`, you have this piece of code:

```
if (awards.getQuantity()<1)
    Picasso.with(view.getContext()).load(R.drawable.sold).into(viewHolder.checker);
else
if (awards.getIsVip())
    Picasso.with(view.getContext()).load(R.drawable.vip).into(viewHolder.checker);
```

Change it to something like this (it depends on how you want to show/hide your view. As it stands, you're not handling the case where you need to hide it!):

```
if (awards.getQuantity()<1) {
    Picasso.with(view.getContext()).load(R.drawable.sold).into(viewHolder.checker);
}
else {
    // hide viewHolder.checker here
}
if (awards.getIsVip()) {
    Picasso.with(view.getContext()).load(R.drawable.vip).into(viewHolder.checker);
}
```

**Note:** As a general piece of advice, always use curly brackets to avoid such bugs and confusion.